# How do I create a React Native project using Yarn?

Tags: android, npm, react-native, yarnpkg

I am running the following commands in the DOS console on a Windows 7 (64-bit) machine.

```
npm install -g yarn
yarn add global react-native
yarn add global react-native-cli

react-native init sample
```

After running `react-native init sample`, the console was closed.

The error log shows:

```
D:\Mobile>"$basedir/../../Users/pramaswamy/AppData/Local/Yarn/.global/node_modules/.bin/react-native.cmd"   "$@" 

D:\Mobile>exit $?
```

Comment: If you are using windows you should install using Chocolatey: choco install yarn

Answer (score 63, accepted):

I think you're adding global dependencies wrong, and you shouldn't need to install `react-native`, globally or locally. `react-native init` will create a `package.json` with `react-native` listed as a dependency.

You should be able to install `react-native-cli` globally with `yarn global add react-native-cli`, not `yarn add global react-native-cli`.

Here  `yarn run android` command will be used to run the react native app using yarn package manager, and `yarn start` will start the node JS server.

You should be fine with running the following:

```
npm install -g yarn
yarn global add react-native-cli
react-native init sample
yarn run android
yarn start
```

Comment: Note that Yarn discourage installing yarn via npm as of now.

Comment: react-native-cli is outdated

Comment: The React Native docs state: "If you previously installed a global *react-native-cli* package, please remove it as it may cause unexpected issues." https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup#creating-a-new-application

Answer (score 20):

NEW SEP 2019,
now it's more simple, use node10 and expo: (easy way)

```
npm install -g expo-cli

*to create project:

    expo init AwesomeProject

    cd AwesomeProject
    npm start

*install the app 'expo' on your phone, and scan the qr code for the project and you can start to view your app
```

more info:
        https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

> UPDATE OCT 2018 Create React Native App (now discontinued) has been merged with Expo CLI
>   You can now use expo init to create your project. See Quick Start in
>   the Expo documentation for instructions on getting started using Expo
>   CLI.

Unfortunately, `react-native-cli` is *outdated*. Starting 13 March 2017, use `create-react-native-app` instead. Moreover, you shouldn't install Yarn with NPM. Instead, use one of the methods on the `yarn` [installation page](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/install/).

#### 1. Install `yarn`

**Via NPM.** According to its [installation docs](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/install/), you shouldn't install `yarn` via `npm`, but if necessary, you can still install it with a pre-v5 version of `npm`.

UPDATE 2018  - OCTOBER

Node 8.12.0 and NPM 6.4.1 is already compatible with create-react-native-app. Really some minors previous versions too. You don't need more downgrade your npm.

**On Ubuntu.**

```
curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list
```

**On macOS,** use Homebrew or MacPorts.

`brew install yarn`
`sudo port install yarn`

#### 2. Install the Create React Native App

`yarn global add create-react-native-app`

#### 3. Update your shell environment

`source ~/.bashrc`

#### 4. Create a React native project

`create-react-native-app myreactproj`

Answer (score 8):

You got the order wrong. You should be

```
yarn add global react-native-cli
yarn add react-native
react-native init sample
```

Answer (score 2):

Please You visit [Bug](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/2192)

```
yarn global add react-native-cli
```

with

```
react-native --version
```

and I get **"$basedir/../../Users/juvasquezg/AppData/Local/Yarn/config/global/node_modules/.bin/react-native.cmd" "$@"**

`the system cannot find the path specified`

Go to **C:\Program Files\nodejs**  and I saw:

- react-native
- react-native.cmd
- react-native.cmd.cmd

The fix is to delete react-native.cmd and rename react-native.cmd.cmd to react-native.cmd

The Solution [#1324 (comment)](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/1324#issuecomment-256078658)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create app using yarn instead of npx;

`yarn dlx react-native init ExampleApp` this command will be helpful.

According to the react native documentation we should `use npx react-native init AwesomeProject` command

For more info about "yarn dlx":  https://yarnpkg.com/cli/dlx

Yarn global is deprecated. If you run `yarn global` you will get an error.

[image]

> Usage Error: The 'yarn global' commands have been removed in 2.x -
> consider using 'yarn dlx' or a third-party plugin instead

But yarn dlx won't work like `yarn global` or `npm install <module> --global`

Answer (score 1):

It is now:

```
yarn dlx create-react-native-app
```

then follow the instructions.

`cd project_name` into the project folder and do:

```
yarn install
```

then try with:

```
yarn web
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also do

```
yarn dlx expo-cli
```

then:

```
expo init project_name
```

and follow the instructions

after finishing `cd project_name` and try

```
yarn web
```

Comment: this was way better!