# Expo : cannot find a module LogReporter

Tags: react-native, expo

I have created a React Native Project and I was trying to open that project in Expo XDE. It throws the following error:

> `Cannot find module ...\node_modules\expo\tools\LogReporter`

Firstly I created a React Native project by cloning a KitchenSink Project.
Link:

[NativeBase-KitchenSink](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase-KitchenSink)

When I started the project by issuing series of commands inside the project root directory:

`npm install` and then `expo start`

I saw that the app.json was also not proper, which was the following:

```
{
  "name": "NativebaseKitchenSink",
  "displayName": "NativebaseKitchenSink"
}
```

After issuing `expo start` react-native reported that the `app.json` is not to be found in the current directory.

> [17:05:08] Starting project at
>   D:\Projects\ReactNativeProjects\AwesomeProject [17:05:10] Error:
>   Missing app.json. See https://docs.expo.io/ [17:05:10] Couldn't start
>   project. Please fix the errors and restart the project. [17:05:10]
>   Error: Couldn't start project. Please fix the errors and restart the
>   project.
>       at C:\xdl@51.4.0\src\Project.js:1565:11
>       at Generator.next ()
>       at step (C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\xdl\build\Project.js:2033:191)
>       at C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\xdl\build\Project.js:2033:361
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)

I changed app.json to:

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "AwesomeProject",
    "description": "A Kitchen Sink project.",
    "slug": "AwesomeProject",
    "privacy": "public",
    "sdkVersion": "30.0.0",
    "platforms": [
      "ios",
      "android"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
    "android": {
      "package": "com.abhsax.first"
    },
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/logo.png",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splashscreen.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ]
  }
}
```

There were some updates in the project when I issued `npm install` again. Then I issued:

```
expo start
```

This error came:

> (node:2044) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Cannot find
>   module
>   'D:\Projects\ReactNativeProjects\AwesomeProject\node_modules\expo\tools\LogReporter'

Why am I getting this error, and how can I fix it?

Comment: You don't provide enough information to let people help you.

Comment: Can you make sure that the `expo` package is installed in your project? You can remove the `node_modules` folder and then run `npm install` or `yarn` again in your project folder.

Comment: Sadhu I still have this problem, did you solve it?

Comment: @Mizlul If you have the same problem, could you add a comment with a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Someone with mod edit privileges can edit it into the question later. As Nyri0 commented, this question as it stands doesn't have enough information.

Comment: @Mizlul, please provide a git repo which can be used to reproduce and fix the error

Comment: Can you post your Package.json file ?

Comment: Is expo in the package.json under `dependencies` or `devDependencies` ?

Comment: @Mizlul Sorry for late reply... Yes I Solved this. I had some problem with my npm install.

Answer (score 10):

check your `package.json` if it contains all needed dependencies and run `npm install` in the home directory of the project

if a package is missing you can add it with

```
npm install <package_name> --save
```

if you are using **yarn** run:

```
yarn add expo
```

Answer (score 9):

I did:

```
yarn add expo
```

and it worked for me =)

Answer (score 6):

See docs:

[introducing-button-yarn-and-a-public-roadmap](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2016/11/08/introducing-button-yarn-and-a-public-roadmap)

and

[npm-vs-yarn-in-react-native](https://medium.com/@rizwanchouhan/npm-vs-yarn-in-react-native-fbcffb932028)

These documents say that since the project configured using Yarn, you have to follow `Yarn` way. `[Note: There is a file yarn.lock inside the root directory of the project, you have posted]`

Therefore such projects are dealt by following the instructions in the documentation.

Please see [How do I create a React Native project using Yarn?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40011693/787399) to actually create a `react-native` project using `Yarn`.

And please be sure to remove `node_modules` folder and issue command `npm install` before adding `react native CLI` using `yarn`. You have to remove `package-lock.json` from your project root. This will be to prevent mixing different package managers : `npm` and `yarn`.

Instead, it will be a good idea not to use `npm`, and in order to generate `node_modules`, just issue command:

```
yarn
```

Last link recommends to install every package you need using yarn, and not to use any other package manager:

```
yarn global add react-native-cli
```

to add react-native:

```
yarn add react-native
```

to add missing packages:

```
yarn add react-base --save
```

and to install expo using yarn:

```
yarn add expo
```

install expo-cli

```
yarn add expo-cli
```

It is possible that you can do without `Expo`. Just focus on `react-native` and `yarn`.

Generate `android` and `ios` folders:

```
react-native eject
```

Start yarn:

```
yarn start
```

run build of your choice, and make sure the SDKs are installed.

```
react-native run-android
```

Please also see: [Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined, on a KitchenSink demo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52989974/787399)

Happy Coding :-)

Comment: thanks a lot, @Abhinav this was the best solution I got so far. I spent my whole day to rectify the error and your solution saved my day. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Install the Expo modules

npm install  --save

i.e.

npm install expo --save

Answer (score -1):

rollback with npm install -g expo-cli@2.4.3