# How do I properly install expo-cli with yarn?

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm, expo

I'm trying to install `expo-cli`.

When I use `npm install -g expo-cli`, it installs with the below output.

[image: Output of npm install -g expo-cli]

When I try to run the `expo` command I get an error that the system cannot find the path specified. I then uninstalled with `npm uninstall -g expo-cli`

I uninstalled `node` and `npm` and cleaned up my system, then I tried installing `expo-cli` with `yarn global add expo-cli`. It installed with the following output.

[image: Output of yarn global add expo-cli]

After this, `expo init` command worked. But when I run `expo start` in a project folder I get the below output.

[image: Output of expo-start]

I don't know what else to do. I'm on Windows 10.

Comment: How did you install yarn?

Comment: And did you reinstall Node and NPM?

Comment: Sorry I'm replying this late. I was on the move yesterday and I didn't even get a notification on my SO android app.

Comment: I have reinstalled Node and NPM

Comment: I installed yarn using chocolatey

Comment: I've had similar issues in the past. I would suggest uninstalling yarn with Chocolatey, then installing yarn with `npm i -g yarn`

Comment: hmm... so under your node_modules\expo\tools, can you find LogReporter.js? If not, you may need to install your packages again, yarn or npm

Answer (score 31):

**For Yarn:**

If you want to save expo-cli package globally then try

```
yarn global add expo-cli
```

and if you want expo-cli to be available in the folder in which you are currently working then use

```
yarn add expo-cli
```

**For npm:**

```
npm install expo-cli --global
```

or

```
npm install expo-cli
```

Comment: Do you know how to do this with yarn 2?

Answer (score 2):

There's a similar issue reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49151286/expo-cannot-find-a-module-logreporter?rq=1).  You can try adding expo to your local project to see if that helps.

Try:

```
yarn add expo
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to upgrade my Expo SKD from 46 to 47. Since version 46 expo-cli was incorporated into expo and it's also no longer recommended to be installed globally but locally, I used yarn to upgrade expo.

From my local project terminal, (MacOS Monterey, using VS Code) I ran this:

```js
yarn add expo@^47.0.6
```

**-- Be sure to only upgrade Expo SKD Client versions one at a time**, (**DO NOT Skip versions**, e.g. go from say 46 to 48).

Sourced: [Upgrade Expo SDK](https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/upgrading-expo-sdk-walkthrough/?redirected)

Answer (score -1):

1. npm cache clean -f
2. npm install -g n
3. sudo n stable

Answer (score -4):

You want to save `expo-cli` package globally then try

```
yarn add global expo-cli
```

Comment: this adds it as a local dep

Comment: `yarn add global expo-cli` will try to install two packages: "global" and "expo-cli". Global comes before the add, see https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/global/