# Cannot find module 'expo/tools/LogReporter'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, native-base

I want to run **NativeBase's** **KitchenSink** in my device.

So I clone it from git, here is the link: https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase-KitchenSink

After clone I run `npm install` and after that `npm start`. It works fine and tells me to open it on my local host but there I find only this:

[image]

The link goes to React Native's main page, nothing special. But I want to see whats going on in my app, so I run `npm install -g expo-cli` , after that `expo start` and I got this error:

> [13:51:33] Error: Missing app.json. See https://docs.expo.io/
>
> [13:51:33] No Expo configuration found. Are you sure this is a project
>   directory?

After that I change my `app.json` from this:

```
{
  "name": "NativebaseKitchenSink",
  "displayName": "NativebaseKitchenSink"
}
```

To this:

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "My Project Name",
    "slug": "myProjectName",
    "privacy": "public",
    "sdkVersion": "32.0.0",
    "platforms": [
      "ios",
      "android"
    ],
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "default",
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],

    "androidStatusBar": {},

    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    }
  }
}
```

And running `expo start` gives me this error:

> [14:03:28] Cannot find module 'expo/tools/LogReporter'

After that I find some solutions and all they are similar with each other, here is the one of them: https://forums.expo.io/t/solved-cannot-find-module-expo-tools-logreporter/16833

And here: [Expo : cannot find a module LogReporter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49151286/expo-cannot-find-a-module-logreporter)

Even I find the question with exactly the same problem in russian community, and I try the solution from there and it was helpless too, here it is (**its in russian**): http://qaru.site/questions/2455460/expo-cannot-find-a-module-logreporter

So I will be grateful for the help))

Answer (score 0):

You'r app.json don't look like app.json of expo.
Do you tried react-native run-ios instead of expo start?

You cann't use expo-cli to vanilla react native app.