# Cannot find module 'metro-symbolicate/src/Symbolication'

Tags: react-native, expo

I got this error while i follow the tutorial on react native of Mosh ( youtube link )
I'm totaly new to react native so someone can explain what is going on and how to solve it ?

here the prompt i get when i launch `expo start` command

```
    MacBook-Pro-de-MAC:DoneWithIt mac$ expo start
Starting project at /Users/mac/Documents/projects/loto/test/DoneWithIt
Developer tools running on http://localhost:19002
Unable to reach Expo servers. Falling back to using the cached dependency map (bundledNativeModules.json) from the package "expo" installed in your project.
Cannot find module 'metro-symbolicate/src/Symbolication'
Require stack:
- /Users/mac/Documents/projects/loto/test/DoneWithIt/node_modules/metro/src/Server/symbolicate.js
- /Users/mac/Documents/projects/loto/test/DoneWithIt/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js
- /Users/mac/Documents/projects/loto/test/DoneWithIt/node_modules/metro/src/index.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/dev-server/build/metro/importMetroFromProject.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/dev-server/build/HermesBundler.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/dev-server/build/MetroDevServer.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/xdl/build/start/startDevServerAsync.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/xdl/build/internal.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/xdl/build/index.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/build/exp.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/bin/expo.js
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Expo : cannot find a module LogReporter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49151286/expo-cannot-find-a-module-logreporter)