# React Native cannot npx init project, cannot find module error

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, npx

npx react-native init MyApp

> √ Downloading template × Copying template error Error: Cannot find
>   module
>   'C:\Users\%%%%\AppData\Local\Temp\rncli-init-template-rVvcjE\node_modules\react-native\template.config'
>   Require stack:
>   - C:\Users\%%%%%\node_modules\react-native\node_modules@react-native-community\cli\build\commands\init\template.js
>   - C:\Users\%%%%%\node_modules\react-native\node_modules@react-native-community\cli\build\commands\init\init.js
>   - C:\Users\%%%%%\node_modules\react-native\node_modules@react-native-community\cli\build\commands\init\index.js
>   - C:\Users\%%%%%\node_modules\react-native\node_modules@react-native-community\cli\build\commands\index.js
>   - C:\Users\%%%%%\node_modules\react-native\node_modules@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js
>   - C:\Users\%%%%%\node_modules\react-native\cli.js

npx react-native info

> info Fetching system and libraries information... System:
>       OS: Windows 10 10.0.18363
>       CPU: (8) x64 AMD Ryzen 5 2500U with Radeon Vega Mobile Gfx
>       Memory: 3.88 GB / 6.80 GB   Binaries:
>       Node: 12.13.1 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.EXE
>       npm: 6.12.1 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD   SDKs:
>       Android SDK:
>         API Levels: 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29
>         Build Tools: 28.0.3, 29.0.2   IDEs:
>       Android Studio: Version  3.5.0.0 AI-191.8026.42.35.5977832   npmPackages:
>       react-native: 0.61.5 => 0.61.5

To avoid unnecessary responses npm uninstall react-native-cli -g has been already done.

rncli-init-template-rVvcjE from the file path mentioned above does not even exist and I am not sure why. Thanks, everybody for help in advance I am new to stack overflow I have only been programming competitively so far. No stranger to algorithms but for cross-platform development frameworks, I'm a newbie.

Comment: If i have not provided enough information, please do ask :) sorry again, help a newbie out.

Answer (score 4):

Try to init with yarn. Yarn has a better performance than npm ([link July 2019](https://www.ryadel.com/en/yarn-vs-npm-pnpm-2019/)).

Install yarn first

```
npm install -g yarn
```

Install react-native-cli. If don't work try with sudo.

```
yarn global add react-native-cli
```

Create yout project

```
react-native init myapp
```

[Related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40011693/how-do-i-create-a-react-native-project-using-yarn/45780332)

Comment: Unfortunately that does not help, neither does anything else i have found online :(

Comment: I am seeing the exact same issue. If i do "npm install -g react-native-cli" I am then able to init an app using "npx react-native init MyApp" however i then have later issues in my app and SO answers say you should not have a global version of "react-native-cli"

Answer (score 0):

1. first uninstall your nodejs using nodejs setup(the same version you have installed)
2. reboot your computer (optional)
3. after all install again nodejs (nodejs.org/en/download/) and all will be fine.

Comment: I get this problem because I was playing with node files (npm to be more specific). 