# I want to start with react native without expo method.. i found this error

Tags: react-native

[I got this error when i am trying to run my app in original device, everything according to react-native documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9kzi.png)

Answer (score 1):

Try running your app with the **yarn** command, otherwise run **npm-doctor** to make sure all your packages are updated and fixed.

otherwise try installing dependencies for expo using :

```
npm install -g yarn
yarn add global react-native
yarn add global react-native-cli
react-native init sample
```

here's a quick link to the npm-doctor documentation:

- https://docs.npmjs.com/cli-commands/doctor.html

Also here's some tutorial on running react-native app using yarn command:

- [How do I create a React Native project using Yarn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40011693/how-do-i-create-a-react-native-project-using-yarn)

Comment: Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper . this error i got,, andorid emulator n all are working . but when installing app in the emulator ,, i got this error

Comment: There is an issue supporting JDK 14, try downloading gradle version 6.3 and this will fix your problem

Answer (score 0):

I find this solution .. i just replace 6.2 with 6.3

in android/gradle/ gradle-wrapper.properties

distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.3-all.zip